# Iterate over multiple Set Java

Tags: java, java-6

I want to iterate over a multiple Set.

```
Set<Pair<Long,Order>> getOrderSet();
```

This is my method. I am looking for a way to get the values from Order. Order is a class , that has has method like getOrderId() , in which I am interested.

Below is my iterator code.

```
Iterator iter = getOrderSet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println("Order " +iter.next());
}
```

I am confused how can I obtained the values from Order Class.

Any imputs would be nice.

Thanks !!!

Comment: by using the interface provided by your `Pair` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use generics, your IDE would be able to help:

```
Iterator<Pair<Long,Order>> iter = getOrderSet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
      Pair<Long,Order> pair = iter.next();
      System.out.println("ID " + pair.getFirst());
      System.out.println("Order " + pair.getSecond());
}
```

You can also use the "for each" syntax, like this:

```
for (Pair<Long,Order> pair : getOrderSet()) {
      System.out.println("ID " + pair.getFirst());
      System.out.println("Order " + pair.getSecond());
}
```